# Any reason not to use $(test).stuff(); vs test.stuff(); given that test = $('something');?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Google isn't helping me figure this one out. Is there any reason not to do the following:

```
var test = $('something');
$(test).stuff();
```

Instead of the doing it this way:

```
var test = $('something');
test.stuff();
```

Basically I find the code much easier to read when it's in the jQuery selector format, even though it doesn't need to be.

Both methods appear to work the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. I didn't think of simply adding the dollar sign to the beginning of object variables. That makes it stand out enough for me :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first one can be significantly slower, depending on the size of the object. If you only use it a couple times it won't make that much a difference, but if you use it a lot maybe you could use this popular naming scheme:

If a variable contains a jQuery object prepend the variable name with `$`. Name everything else normally, and don't name any variables that do not contain jQuery objects with a $. So you would write:

```
var $test = $('something');
$test.stuff();
```

Which makes it clear that test is a jQuery object if you've been following the same naming convention.

Comment: In fact this is a good thing to do anytime you're going to use the same jQuery object more than once. This way you cache the jQuery object instead of running the same jQuery method to get the same jQuery object over and over again. Often you can see this with `var $this = $(this);`.

Comment: +1 though I believe 'ever so slightly slower' is pretty subjective. The benchmarks I saw showed a 12-15% performance gain by your suggestion.

Comment: @AlienWebGuy, you're right. For some reason I thought jQuery just returned the object it was passed, but it turns out it makes a clone of the whole thing, so it could be quite expensive if the object is large. `$($('*'));` as an example will clone every HTMLElement on your page. I edited my post, to make it a significant performance difference.

Answer (score 7):

This is from the jQuery Docs:

```
Cloning jQuery Objects

When a jQuery object is passed to the $() function, a clone of the object is created. This new jQuery object references the same DOM elements as the initial one.
```

So the difference is that jQuery is making a clone of the jQuery object being passed to the $() function (which creates a small amount of extra overhead).

Link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 5):

`test.stuff()` is faster.

Here's some benchmarking evidence: http://jsperf.com/selector-variation-test

Comment: +1 for the site from me as well. how comes I never heard of it :)

Answer (score 4):

You'll take a performance hit for no good reason doing it the first way. The reason for this is that you are "re-jQueryifying" it. What I recommend is to write it like this `var $test = $('something');` it is very clear that the variable is a jQuery object when you do that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the first method is correct, I think once you've declared a variable it's just that name. If you want similar syntax you can declare the variable as `$test` and be fine.

Comment: The first one works, but it is re-running code that doesn't need to.